# Is there a way to add webkit specific styles on a layer?

Tags: css, framerjs

For example can I add 
`-webkit-backdrop-filter: saturate(1.8) blur(20px);` on a Layer to quickly simulate background blur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a Layer's `style` property to set custom css styles. Example:

```
layerB = new Layer
    image: Utils.randomImage()

layerA = new Layer

layerA.style["-webkit-backdrop-filter"] = "saturate(1.8) blur(20px)"
```